# What is the sum multiple exponential distributions?

Tags: poisson-process, exponential-distribution

I have data about the interarrival times of some process. With the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test I could not reject the hypothesis that the data comes not from an exponential distribution. So I assumed that the interarrival times are exponential distributed. Also that my process is a Poisson Point process.

The process can be divided in multiple classes. Like a queue, some people have long questions, others are done within seconds. Some classes have enough data to fit an exponential distribution. But others have e.g. five data points or less. I can not fit a distribution with only five observations. I think it is reasonable to assume all those classes are exponentially distributed.

Is there mathematical proof that the sum of multiple exponential distributions is exponentially distributed?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! The exponential distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution with shape parameter 1. The sum of multiple exponential distributions with the same rate parameter will be a gamma distribution, but not an exponential distribution, since the shape parameter will be larger than 1. If the rate parameters are different, it will not even be gamma. So the sum of multiple exponential distributions will not be exponentially distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent with $\mathrm{Expo}(\lambda)$ distribution. We compute the density of $X_1+X_2$ by convolution:
\begin{align}
f_{X_1+X_2}(t) &= f_{X_1}\star f_{X_2}(t)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{X_1}(\tau)f_{X_2}(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda \tau}\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-\tau)}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t} \int_0^t\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \lambda ( \lambda t)e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t).
\end{align}

Assuming now that $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ has density $\frac{\lambda (\lambda t)^{n-1} e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}$, we compute the density of $S_{n+1} = S_n + X_{n+1}$ again by convolution:
\begin{align}
f_{S_{n+1}}(t) &= f_{S_n}\star f_{X_{n+1}}(t)\\
&= \int_0^t \frac{\lambda (\lambda \tau)^{n-1} e^{-\lambda \tau}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda (t-\tau)}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&=\frac{\lambda^2e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}\int_0^t (\lambda\tau)^{n-1} \ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \frac{\lambda^2e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!} \frac{(\lambda  t)^n}{\lambda  n}\\
&= \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!},
\end{align}
so the density is of this form for all positive integers $n$ by mathematical induction.